# What's the right name for CTL-]?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

From my .emacs:

```lisp
(defun flip-window () "Flip this window" (interactive)
       (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer)))

;; later
(global-set-key [(control ?])] 'flip-window)
```

It works great, but I have two questions:

1. is there a built-in function to flip to most recently visited buffer?
2. While the above works at emacs startup, it causes problems when I'm trying to update settings, there's a parse error caused by the ?].  So is there a better way to express the control-] keystroke?

Comment: Be careful about setting `C-]` without rebinding its original command `abort-recursive-edit.` This command is incredibly useful and sometimes necessary to get out of recursive edits when `C-g` (`keyboard-quit`) won't work (although the command sequence `ESC ESC ESC` ('keyboard-escape-quit') should also work in those situations).

Comment: Too many questions in your question. Please post separate questions for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to the question 2.
You may try the kbd function while setting the key binding.

Like so:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-]") 'flip-window)
```

And to the question 1: I guess there is no built in function for that. Emacs redux teaches us to implement it like:

```
(defun er-switch-to-previous-buffer ()
  "Switch to previously open buffer. Repeated invocations toggle between the two most recently open buffers."
  (interactive)
  (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer (current-buffer) 1)))
```

This is part of Emacs Prelude distro. See https://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/28/switch-to-previous-buffer/

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, you can get a description of any key combination in emacs using using the <kbd>C-h k</kbd> key combination, which runs the `describe-key` function. You'll have to read the textual form of your input from the description buffer. If you want to programmatically retrieve a string containing your key combination, you could also run the following Elisp code:

```lisp
(destructuring-bind ((str . code)) (help--read-key-sequence)
         (help-key-description str code))
```

It will prompt you for input in the minibuffer and return a string, such as e.g. `"C-]"`.